# Exercises to alleviate shoulder cramp

Tags: exercise, muscle, cramps

For some reason my shoulders are cramped up since last night. Lacking any other probable causes I blame temperature.

Now I've been having trouble moving both my shoulders for a couple of hours already. What exercises would alleviate the cramp the fastest?

Comment: If your shoulder has been cramped up for hours and you can barely move them, you have (or had, back in 2015) something more serious going on.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago my right shoulder had bursitis and I could barely move it, if at all, due to excruciating pain. I know what you are mentioning is probably more subtle compared to that, but even today my shoulder isn't back to 100%. However, when my shoulder gets stiff or feels like its weaker, I usually do 5 different exercises and within no time my shoulder feels back to about 99%. The exercises I do that should help you as well are:

1. Front Dumbbell Raise
2. Dumbbell Shoulder Press
3. Dumbbell Side Lateral Raises
4. Bent-Over Dumbbell Rear Deltoid Raise
5. Dumbbell Upright Row

I usually do three to four sets of these each, from 10-20 reps depending on the weight. Definitely start with light weights at the start until you feel comfortable going up.

Comment: I'd even suggest doing these movements without any weight if you are in severe pain.